# Referencing a system function from a DB with a lower compatibility level

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, functions, compatibility-level

I need to be able to parse a string array with STRING_SPLIT on a SQL 2016 instance. The vendor has required the one user DB we have access to be set with a compatibility level of 100 while the system DBs are at 130. Can STRING_SPLIT and other system functions be referenced when the context is set to the 100-level DB?

Comment: No, not without dynamic SQL/procs used in the context of the other databases.

Comment: @ErikDarling Are you sure? What about `sp_ms_marksystemobject`

Comment: If you feel comfortable with suggesting it, sure. I haven't used it much, and only tried it once [sort of recently](https://bornsql.ca/blog/remember-this-if-you-want-to-use-sp_/). One thing I dislike about it is that there's no way to undo it without updating system views.

Answer (score 0):

**Since `master` has the correct compatibility level, you can always execute `STRING_SPLIT` there.**

So we can create inline TVF functions to execute it, then mark them as system functions so you can access them anywhere.

```
USE master;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION STRING_SPLITV
(@string varchar(max), @separator char(1))
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN

SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@string, @separator);
GO

CREATE FUNCTION STRING_SPLITN
(@string nvarchar(max), @separator nchar(1))
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN

SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@string, @separator);
GO

EXEC sp_ms_marksystemobject 'STRING_SPLITV';
EXEC sp_ms_marksystemobject 'STRING_SPLITN';
```

Note that `sp_ms_marksystemobject` is an undocumented system procedure, use at your own risk.

You can now use these functions in every database without schema-qualifying

```
USE YourDB;
GO

SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLITV('a,b,c', ',');
```

If you do not use `sp_ms_marksystemobject` you will still have access, but must qualify it with database and schema. If you have no access to `master` on a regular basis, perhaps create it in `model`, then it will appear in `tempdb` on restart.

*Note: This is a copy of [a similar question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69928018/14868997) by me from Stack Overflow*